# Is there really no way to get JIRA Studio to work with Mercurial?

Tags: jira

I absolutely hate hosting and having to maintain my own project management system, and I really like JIRA. Atlassian's JIRA Studio hosted offering seems very appealing, but my team has been using Mercurial for months now, and I don't want to go back to Subversion.

Is there any way, supported or unsupported, to get Mercurial on the hosted JIRA Studio offering?

Comment: If you haven't heard by now, it appears FogBugz might be able to meet your [CI](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/782/hosted-continuous-integration/1463#1463) needs now.

Comment: MikeCI's web site always seem down. And while it was not a requirement in the question, we're a .NET shop and they really mostly do Java. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the apps integrated in JIRA Studio do not yet have Mercurial support. For example, JIRA Studio 2.2 integrates Fisheye and Crucible 2.2.4. These products only gained very early Mercurial support in version 2.3 (http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/whats-new.jsp). I'd guess that JIRA Studio won't support Mercurial repositories at least until JIRA Studio integrates applications that have full support for Mercurial.

I'd suggest going to http://support.atlassian.com and creating an issue that registered your interest in making use of Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not directly answering your question, another option you may want to consider is using [Kiln](http://kilnhg.com). Among its notable features are:

- FogBugz integration
- Mecurial source control
- Integrated code reviews

You can use the hosted version, or bring the program to your own server.

Comment: We're on Kiln right now. I love it, but I really need continuous integration. That's why we're looking to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start of by saying I have not used JIRA before.  I looked at their site and it looks like they only allow you to use Subversion to check code into your online repository.  If that is the case then you are most likely stuck with Subversion if you stick with JIRA.  In this case I would contact JIRA and see what they can do.  After all, if you are using them now then you probably have a service contract with them.

Now if JIRA allows you to upload files to an FTP repository then why don't you just use Mercurial locally and then upload your code via ftp?  Mercurial has a mode where all of the changes are put into a .hg folder within your solution. That means uploading and downloading everything shouldn't be to horrible.

Another option would be to leave JIRA.  Have you checked out http://bitbucket.org/?  It is Mercurial's hosted code option. It looks to be much cheaper than JIRA but also lack a few of the features.  If they happen to be features you don't use then you might be able to make the switch easily.

Comment: I'm currently using FogBugz, but I want to switch to JIRA Studio. JIRA Studio isn't just JIRA, it also has Continuous Integration (Bamboo) and some other nice features.

Comment: Then I think you are stuck.  I would contact JIRA directly.  You could always run your own Continuous integration server :)